# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SQL must not be null

Tags: sql-server, xml, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Iam using jdbc templete for fetching data from database wheerein all my queries are stored in xml file

Found a weird problem

initial query in xml file was

`select * from invoice where  YEAR(INV.BILL_DATE) =? AND MONTH(INV.BILL_DATE) = ?`

its working fine as above after changing above query

```
select * from invoice where (INV.BILL_DATE >= CAST(? AS DATE)) AND (INV.BILL_DATE <= CAST(? AS DATE))
```

Iam getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SQL must not be null

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SQL must not be null

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SQL must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.<init>(JdbcTemplate.java:1515)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:716)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:726)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:776)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Just by changing the SQL statement in `jdbcTemplate.query("...")` I can't reproduce the exception.

Comment: In case the exception is `SQL must not be null` it means that the SQL statement given to the JdbcTemplate was actually `null`. It looks like the issue is not the SQL statement itself, but the operation of reading the statement from the XML file.

Comment: @Roland if i revert below query app runs fine